# How to combine two python source codes?

Tags: python

I want to use this on the same line... Is it possible?

I want to increase the count even if it's just one of the two. Is it possible?

```
if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:

  COUNTER += 1
```

and

```
if DIS > DIS_AR_THRESH:

  COUNTER += 1
```

Comment: use `or` to combine conditions. `if ear < xxx or dis > yyy:`

Comment: thx bro :) have a good day~

Answer (score 0):

You use the `or` in the form:

```
if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH or DIS > DIS_AR_THRESH:
```

The opposite would be `and` where both conditions needs to be True.

Comment: I don't know if you are using a tool to translate or to grammar check, but please double check if your final post is understandable and if the code is actually runnable. [I've fixed it for you now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70139075/revisions), but simple typos like the "News" and the `If` with capital letter can be fixed by you.